# problem with '-' and '&' string in mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a search engine in PHP. When a search normally it's OK. Search text is 'company', and in the database there is 'company' in the field...

The problem is when the search text is `&company` or `-company` and the data is `&company` or `-company` there is no match. why?

problem with the `-` and `&` string...

Comment: Are you using Fulltext Search? The & and - are reserved characters in Fulltext. (At least in MSSQL)

Comment: @Jose Chama: In mySQL too, at least the `-`.

Comment: but sometimes it's like com&pany and then,
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE company LIKE '%company%'
is not good...

Comment: I answered with the workaround I did. This is a very good question, and I could not find any solution in the web that really convinced me.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your search terms in quotes. This should help mysql know you mean those characters literally in fulltext search:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename MATCH (company) AGAINST ('"&company"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

SELECT * FROM tablename MATCH (company) AGAINST ('"-company"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FullText Search then the & and - are reserved characters. I could not find any nice solution to this problem. What I did is just remove the special character and run the full text search. For example if they are looking for At&t I run a search for "AT" "T", but if you have noise words At and A are in there and you will not get any results.

Another solution is to detect when they are requesting a special character and run a LIKE '%&Company%' search instead of a full text search, but this will affect the performance of the query.

Comment: It seems to be possible to change word characters if you have access to mysql itself: See the comments in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html